# java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 8 > 6

Tags: java, mysql, sql

When I try retrieve the whole record and display it from database. Its showing an error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 8 > 6.
```

I am not able to figure this out. pls help.

JAVA CODE

```
public ArrayList viewAllDrivers() {
        ArrayList allDrivers=new ArrayList();

        try {
            String sql= "select * from adddriver ORDER BY dname";
            rs =DBConnection.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()) {
                ArrayList one = new ArrayList();
                one.add(rs.getInt(1));
                one.add(rs.getString(2));
                one.add(rs.getString(6));
                one.add(rs.getString(8));
                one.add(rs.getString(9));
                one.add(rs.getString(10));
                one.add(rs.getInt(11));
                allDrivers.add(one);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println (ex);
        }
        return allDrivers;
    }
```

PAGE WHERE I AM TRYING TO SHOW THE RESULT

```
<%
SearchDAO searchDAO = new SearchDAO();
ArrayList all = searchDAO.viewAllDrivers();
int size = all.size();
%>


<table width="95%" align="center"  style="border:#D22929 solid 2px;padding:10px;" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th bgcolor="#D22929" scope="col"><span class="style10">Driver Name </span></th>
    <th bgcolor="#D22929" scope="col"><span class="style10">Address</span></th>
    <th bgcolor="#D22929" scope="col"><span class="style10">City</span></th>
    <th bgcolor="#D22929" scope="col"><span class="style10">Contact</span></th>
    <th bgcolor="#D22929" scope="col"><span class="style10">Country&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></th>
    <th bgcolor="#D22929" scope="col"><span class="style10">Ation</span></th>
  </tr>

<%
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
ArrayList one=(ArrayList)all.get(i);
%>
<tr style="height:30px; padding:4px;">
    <td><div align="center"><%=(String)one.get(1)%></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><%=(String)one.get(2)%></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><%=(String)one.get(3)%></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><%=(String)one.get(4)%>&nbsp;</div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><%=(String)one.get(5)%>&nbsp;</div></td>

</tr>
<% } %>
```

Comment: It's pretty self-explanative. You are accessing column indices that are over the table's size. Double-check your table.

Comment: check the number of columns in your table in your DB. Also, use servlets. you should not have any Java code in your jsp files.

Comment: `ADDDRIVER` table has only 6 columns but you want to get 8th column.

Comment: how many columns does your table `ADDDRIVER` Have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error implies that your `adddriver` only has 6 columns, so 8 is an invalid column index.

This means all of these statements have invalid indices :

```
            one.add(rs.getString(8));
            one.add(rs.getString(9));
            one.add(rs.getString(10));
            one.add(rs.getInt(11));
```

Perhaps your DB table doesn't contain what you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

Always better to explicitly name the column you are retrieving so you dont face such problem.

public ArrayList viewAllDrivers() {
        ArrayList allDrivers=new ArrayList();

```
    try {
        String sql= "select city,address,... from adddriver ORDER BY dname";
        rs =DBConnection.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()) {
            ArrayList one = new ArrayList();
            one.add(rs.getInt(1));
            one.add(rs.getString(2));
            one.add(rs.getString(6));
            one.add(rs.getString(8));
            one.add(rs.getString(9));
            one.add(rs.getString(10));
            one.add(rs.getInt(11));
            allDrivers.add(one);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println (ex);
    }
    return allDrivers;
}
```

You are going out of your column count because that you are encountering this exception