# Table only partially generated

Tags: java, itext

I use the iText5 library to generate a pdf document.
I am trying to create a table in pdf file.
When the number of table rows is greater than 3 it works fine.
But when number of table rows is less than 3, it generates an empty pdf file with no table (only the heading is printed.)

this is my code:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font.FontFamily;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.GrayColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
//import sandbox.WrapToTest;

//@WrapToTest
public class ColumnWidthExample {
   static String f="";

    public static final String DEST = "C:\\Users\\Rahul\\Documents\\Challan_Reports\\";
//    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
//       ColumnWidthExample.createPdf("2017-08-08","anuj");
//    }

    public static String createPdf(String dest,String gname) throws IOException, DocumentException {
         try{

//        for (int counter = 1; counter < 101; counter++) {
//            table.addCell(String.valueOf(counter));
//            table.addCell("key " + counter);
//            table.addCell("value " + counter);
//        }

            Connection con=DB.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from echallan where guarantor_name='"+gname+"' and date='"+dest+"' order by date desc");
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next())

            { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "exists");
                System.out.println(dest+gname+" cpdf");
        File file = new File(DEST+" "+dest+" "+gname+".pdf");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(DEST+""+dest+"_"+gname+".pdf"));
        f=DEST+" "+dest+" "+gname+".pdf";
        document.open();
        document.add(new Chunk(""));
        document.add(new Paragraph("   Report of Guarantor "+gname+" for date "+dest));
        document.add(new Paragraph(""));
        float[] columnWidths = {10, 10, 10,5,5,10,10,5,7,5,10,10,13,10,10};
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);
        table.setWidthPercentage(105);
        table.getDefaultCell().setUseAscender(true);
        table.getDefaultCell().setUseDescender(true);
        Font f = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.NORMAL, GrayColor.GRAYWHITE);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase());

        table.getDefaultCell().setBackgroundColor(new GrayColor(0.75f));
        table.addCell("Merchant\ncode");
         table.addCell("Merchant\nname");
        table.addCell("Invioce");
        table.addCell("Bale\nfrom");
        table.addCell("Bale\nto");
        table.addCell("Total\nbale");
        table.addCell("Station");
        table.addCell("Sort");
        table.addCell("Chart");
        table.addCell("Ex\nmill");
        table.addCell("Rransport");
        table.addCell("Remarks");
        table.addCell("Date");
        table.addCell("Guarantor\nname");
        table.addCell("Guarantor\ncode");
        table.setHeaderRows(3);
        table.setFooterRows(1);
        table.getDefaultCell().setBackgroundColor(GrayColor.GRAYWHITE);
        table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase());
                do{
                    for(int i=1;i<=15;i++){
                    table.addCell(""+rs.getString(i));
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rs.getString(i));}
                    document.add(new Phrase());
                }while(rs.next());
                document.add(table);
        document.close();

                   return "Generated successfully.\n File Saved in \n "+DEST+dest+"_"+gname;
            }
            else
            {
                return "No data found";
            }


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print(e);
            return "unsuccessfull";
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You are looping from 1 to 15 in the do while statement and accessing the column values. Are you sure that the table has 15 columns  ? This looks similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050715/java-sql-sqlexception-column-index-out-of-range-8-6

Answer (score 3):

The problem is related to header/footer rows.

In the next lines you set 2 header and 1 footer rows (#setHeaderRows(int) is responsible to set the number of the header rows and #setFooterRows(int) is responsible to identify how many of the header rows are actually footer rows):

```
table.setHeaderRows(3);
table.setFooterRows (1);
```

So if you add 3 rows, you do not have actual body content (you have only header and footer rows). Thus your result-pdf is empty.

If you run the next snippet

```
            float[] columnWidths = {10, 10, 10,5,5,10,10,5,7,5,10,10,13,10,10};
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);
            table.setHeaderRows(3);
            table.setFooterRows(1);

            int j = 55;
            do{
                j--;
                for(int i=1;i<=15;i++){
                    table.addCell("string " + j);
                    }
                document.add(new Phrase());
            } while(j >0);
            document.add(table);
            document.close();
```

you will see that rows with "string 54" and "string 53" cells repeat each page (as a header). The same for row with "string 52" cells (as a footer).

As far as I understand you have no intenion of keeping header and footer rows. Just remove lines mentioned above and that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain iText generates tables regardless of the number of rows you throw into a table.

Possible avenues for tracking down your problem:
 - iText does not (by default) insert partially filled rows. If you have a table with 5 columns, and you insert only 4 cells, you'll see only the heading.

Also, if you have the freedom of choosing which iText version you can use, please use iText7. A lot of bugfixes, especially related to tables have been made.

Also, check out the documentation at http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/itext-7-tables